# Googlesheets в одном из функций массива выдает ошибку, как её обойти?

Tags: функции, google-spreadsheet

Имеется такая функция массива:

```
={FILTER('Основной 2020'!A:Z;'Основной 2020'!H:H="CHFRUB_TOM");FILTER('ИИС 2020'!A:Z;'ИИС 2020'!H:H="CHFRUB_TOM")}
```

Она работает если на обоих листах фильтр находит хотя-бы одно совпадение.

`FILTER('Основной 2020'!A:Z;'Основной 2020'!H:H="CHFRUB_TOM")` На данном листе нет совпадений нет и из-за этого выдается ошибка всего массива.
Как составить функцию чтобы она работала даже если нет совпадений по фильтру?

Comment: Excel-функция ЕСЛИОШИБКА. В Google-таблицах есть что- то похожее?

Comment: Да есть. Но как правильно её поставить я так и не понял(((

Comment: Поставить куда? Ссылки нет...

Comment: Как правильно подставить функцию Если ошибка?

Comment: Очевидно - ставьте так, чтобы было правильно :) А чтобы другие могли поэкспериментировать...где? **Вы же пример не показываете**. Ну и ждите того, кто подскажет без примера.